# mongodb dyld: Symbol not found: _fchmodat

Tags: mongodb, macos, command-line

I use OSX 10.9 and I've just installed Mongo DB in my /usr/local directory. Followed all the instructions, but when I type mongod in the command line I get this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _fchmodat
  Referenced from: /usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

My ~/.bash_profile looks like this:

```
export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/mongodb
export PATH=$PATH:$MONGO_PATH/bin
```

The item /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib does exist. I tried moving mongodb to my home directory and changed the path but still got the same error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but I downloaded an older version of Mongo DB and it works. Probably a bug that hasn't been fixed in 3.6.2

Comment: Mongo `3.4.16` is the last working one on my Mac OS 10.9.5.